# Capture image after double mouse click event

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, mouselistener

Is there any way to capture image after double click mouse event with java?
I can capture image only at mouse release of double click event.
But capture image is not the image after double click event.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"Capture image*" of what?

Comment: Capture image that is when i click double mouse click. For example, when you click one folder and then will show any file in that folder. I want to capture these files in that folder. But not click photo of that folder.

Comment: @EidoShack if your trying to monitor OS level mouse events, you can't in Java, unless your willing to use JNI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`MouseEvent.getClickCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29).

> Returns the number of mouse clicks associated with this event.

Comment: It returns only double click count. Is there any action event after mouse click event? Can we write custom listener event after mouse click?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

official java tutorial with example using MouseListener